# Table Does Not Exist while using EF CodeFirst 6 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g

I am creating a MVC application using EF 6.0.0.0 and ODP.Net Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version  4.121.2.0 for the data access.

And when I load the Locations/Create.cshtml page I got the following Exception:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
While I have used the link below
[Table Does Not Exist while using EF 6 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403610/table-does-not-exist-while-using-ef-6-and-oracle-manageddataaccess)
Here is how my Context :

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("QAContextConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AMICOS");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
   public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```